# What application is "using my screen" with some kind of overlay?

Tags: security, screen, permissions, accessibility, overlay

I want to turn on accessibility permission to Greenify app. But I'm unable to click "ok".
I also have Twilight and since some security built in the system, I have to disable,  stop or uninstall the aforementioned app which uses an screen overlay to adjust color temperature at sunset and sunrise.

Thing is that I'm still unable to click the ok button. I believe some other app is using some screen overlay but I don't know which one.

How can I find out? Other that trial and error uninstalling and reinstalling every app and their combination (in case there are more than one).

P. S. Already found it,  was Nav Layer.  Anyway, I keep the question for research.

Comment: There are three places to check for screen overlays: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154274/screen-overlay-detected-dialog-turned-off-everything-doesnt-work/157029#157029

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Application which applies the overlay can be found using application permission manager. Simply go through the native application manager (or download from play store) and check whether any app has permission for "Draw over screen" or "Apply Overlay" or "draw over other apps".