# “Screen overlay detected” dialog? Turned off everything, doesn't work

Tags: settings

I started receiving the “Screen overlay detected” dialog when trying to change apps settings.

Tried to turn off all "draw over other apps" as it says here - ["Screen overlay detected" dialog?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126798/screen-overlay-detected-dialog), first without system and then with, but it still doesn't work.

Then, I restored apps to original settings and it just made a bigger mess, dialog continue appearing.
Any way to go back to previous settings???

Thanks!

Comment: Check apps with accessibility privileges, in the Accessibility section of Settings, and turn them all off.

Answer (score 2):

There are three places to check. Mine was caused by the Forest app under Acessibilty.

### Non-system Apps

`Settings` -> `Application Manager` -> `Apps with Overlay Permissions` -> `Apps with Permissions`

### System Apps

Same as above, but with `Show System Apps` turned on

### Accessibility Apps

`Settings` -> `Acessibility` -> Scroll to the bottom. It lists app names. Just turn them all off for now.

Answer (score 1):

**PIE Controls turned out to be the problem for me.**

Long story short, after trying every suggested thing I could find (even disabled permissions of some system apps, I will hopefully remember which ones and will be able to set it back...) I started thinking to myself, *"what application could draw over the screen other than those on this list?"* and realized that I had GravityBox installed through Xposed, and pie controls enabled! As soon as I disabled that (didn't have to turn off the entire module, just setting "enable pie control" to "never" was enough) I was able to finally set permissions!